# Fan page stopped getting traffic after last big overhaul

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I used to have about 1200 fans and my stats would show that my pages would be seen hundreds of times, often over 1,000.

Then there was a major Facebook overhaul, which amongst other things, only showed the most popular posts on people's walls. Ever since, and despite that my FB fan base has grown to more than 1800, so often I get no more then 200 or 300 organic views for a post.

I've researched the best days and times, and after about a year and graphing, I discovered that Tuesday nights at 6:30 are my most popular times. On Tuesdays at 6:30 On August 21st I got 1,000 views, which thrilled me, but since then, on Tuesdays and other days/times I've tried, I'm lucky if even 300 out of my 1,800 even see my post.

What can I possibly do to make sure that the maximum number of fans are at least seeing my posts?

Answer (score 0):

They are trying to get you to pay for promoted posts. The only way to now get all your fans to see your post is to pay for that privilege. If you don't pay, only a subset of your fans will see a post.

Of course the night that I posted this, I saw reports about a new feature. I still can't find the official notification, but this is a good story and it has full instructions.
http://www.nbcnews.com/technology/technolog/responding-criticism-facebook-adds-way-you-really-really-something-1C6669506

So it is a matter of all page owners educating the end users that they need to take an additional step. This isn't great, but it is an improvement.